# Como alterar cor da barra inferior, onde se localizam os botões "Back", "Home" e "App ativos"?

Tags: android, android-layout

Gostaria de saber primeiramente qual o nome do componente (barra) onde se localizam os botões "Back", "Home" e "App ativos" no android. Em aparelhos que não possuem botões físicos para esta função, os componentes vem na tela e ficam sobre os demais (salvo em casos de app rodando em fullscreen).

Também gostaria de saber qual a forma de se altera a cor de fundo desta barra para que fique de acordo as cores do meu App. Para usar de exemplo pode-se comparar com o App da Vivo onde a barra inferior é Roxa assim como as barras superiores.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essa parte chama-se **navigationBarColor** e para alterá-la, faça o seguinte:

Adicione ao seu estilo a linha

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/sua_cor</item>
```

Ou pode se alterar via código Java mesmo

```
getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.sua_cor));
```